# List.files from web accessible folder

Tags: r, url

I need to be able to fill a vector with the files in a web accessible folder.

The variables used in setting the `image_dir` variable are set to the following:

```
msu_path = "http://oer.hpc.msstate.edu/okeanos/"
sub$cruiseID = "EX1504L2"
divespecs$specID = EX1504L2_20150802T223100_D2_DIVE01_SPEC01GEO/
image_dir = http://oer.hpc.msstate.edu/okeanos/ex1504l2/EX1504L2_20150802T223100_D2_DIVE01_SPEC01GEO/

image_dir <- sprintf("%s%s/%s", msu_path, tolower(sub$cruiseID), divespecs$specID)
file_names <- list.files(path = image_dir, pattern = "jpg", ignore.case=TRUE)
```

If I do this exact thing but use a path within my working directory, it works fine.    The `image_dir` does receive a valid URL using the above setting, but it returns `file_names` as a character (empty) value instead of a vector of the .jpg files in that WAF.

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Do you need quotes around the definitions for `divespecs$specID` and `imag_dir`?  What language are you using--could you please add a tag which specifies this?

Comment: Hi, I'm using R.  The first three lines are only to show you what those variables are set to by the time the last two lines are executed.  Sorry, this is my first question ever, so I may not have formatted it correctly.